# Concave Hull with points that have to always intersect

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, concave-hull

I use Concave Hull(Alpha shapes) tool in my set of points in QGIS, it works fine, but I want add some extra points in the beginning, which line of Concave Hull always intersect them.

[image: 1]

In this image, we see a brown polygon in the background, which shows what it should look like. Orange polygon is output of Concave Hull and through the green points I want it to intersect.

Did anyone have this problem too? I think it is necessary to redesign the algorithm in QGIS in some way, but I don't know how.

---

EDIT: Separate images for clear view. It shows just clipping, the entire data are large:

Brown polygon, which shows what it should look like:
[image: 2]

Output of Concave Hull with points, which I want intersect:
[image: 3]

Comment: Could you show the separate data layers as separate images? It is not clear what the image shows.

Comment: Are you saying you want a concave hull with some points, but there's some other points that you want to include in the output polygon *even though they aren't on the concave hull*? Can you add them manually by editing that polygons?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes I can, but it's a lot of data, so it's not very practical to edit manually and I also want it to work for my plugin automatically.